# how to create a mongo db package

Tags: mongodb, go, package

I'd like to build an infrastructure, which is a package for the project. So that other developers can import this package to perform CRUD operations on the DB.

But I've got an error during the test:

```
type Students struct {
    Name      string
    Age int
}

type InsertOneResult struct {
    InsertedID interface{}
}

func dbGetOne(coll, document interface{}) (*InsertOneResult, error) {
...
}

func dbUpdateOne(coll, document interface{}) (*InsertOneResult, error) {
    ...
}

func dbDeleteOne(coll, document interface{}) (*InsertOneResult, error) {
    ...
}

func dbInsertOne(coll, document interface{}) (*InsertOneResult, error) {
    res, err := coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), document)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &InsertOneResult{InsertedID: res[0]}, err
}

func main() {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    coll := client.Database("db").Collection("students")
    data := Students{"Amy", 10}
    res, err := dbInsertOne(coll, data)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("inserted document with ID %v\n", res.InsertedID)
}
```

Here's the error:

```
./main.go:24:18: coll.InsertOne undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it looks like the error could be coming from a type conversion issue. The solution would be to clearly define the type for `coll` as `*mongo.Collection` in the `dbInsertOne()` function. This allows the compiler at compile time to figure out the structure of the input instead of having to rely on an abstract interface.

```
func dbInsertOne(coll *mongo.Collection, document interface{}) (*InsertOneResult, error) {
    res, err := coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), document)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &InsertOneResult{InsertedID: res.InsertedID}, err
}
```

I would further suggest that the 2nd argument `document` should also be a typed known term if possible. e.g.

```
func dbInsertOne(coll *mongo.Collection, document Students)
```

Static typing will help quite a bit and clear up any confusion.

Comment: @Emily Glad to hear it helped. Feel free to upvote this answer so people with similar problems know that it is a potential solution